# Is there a way in R to detect how often a package is used?

Tags: r

Recently, I found that there are many packages that I don't use much, and some of them may never be used again. I would like to delete these packages, but I am worrying that some packages that I often use may depend on these rarely used ones.

So I am wondering whether there is a way in R to detect how often a package is used?

Thank you!

Comment: You can scan through history if you haven't cleared it

Comment: I don't think so. Even looking at history will only tell you what packages you loaded, not the ones loaded by packages you are using. The `search()` function will tell you what packages are loaded. At the end of a session (or script) you could use this to get the packages currently loaded and save that. That gives you the packages loaded but does not guarantee that you actually used any of the functions or data sets in the package.

Comment: You could run `packageDescription("pkg")` to see what other packages are needed to run your favourite package "pkg". Alternatively, you could just delete all packages in the version folder inside your win-library folder, and then as you get back to old scripts, reinstall those packages the scripts used. Unless if they are on CRAN, you should get them back in a pinch. If they're only on Github, a google search for the package name should point you to its location. I guess it's only a problem if the package is no longer available anywhere, but that's a pretty rare occurrence.

Comment: "I would like to delete these packages" Why would you like to delete them?

Comment: Maybe you could save the results of  `sessionInfo()` every once in a while,or *if* it's possible, make it save automatically at the end of each R session. Then you could mine the results after some time. You would be able to see which packages were *attached* and those whose *namespaces* were loaded (so all dependencies should be there).

Comment: Maybe this is usefull, in the `tools` package there is a function called `package_dependecies()`. It can search what dependencies a package has, but also what reverse dependecies a package has.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen a package able to quantify the use of R packages.
Further, I see a risk in simply remove package, as there can be dependencies you are not aware of.

However, there is the package [miniCRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/), which can show you dependencies between packages. So my suggestion would be that you scan for all your packages installed on your system and look for dependencies. In that way you could find packages which can be removed without breaking other packages even if you are using the functionality on a very rare basis.

One more recommendation is to not use system wide installed packages, but use packages dedicated to your projects. There are multiple tools which can be used in this context: [renv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/renv/), [packrat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/packrat/). The goal of such approaches is to get a independent package libraries for each project. If the project is no longer in your focus you can easily remove the packages without touching the functionality of other projects,